# Converting an array of string to a dictionary

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'd like to be able to convert an array of strings into a dictionary where they strings passed in become the keys of the object (and the value is set to `true`):

```
// obj = { foo: true, bar: true );
const obj = toObject("foo", "bar");
```

This is super simple at runtime with JS but I want the types preserved in TS and this is surprising challenging. Here's an implementation that works at runtime but ends up dumping the object out with a type of `all`. Yuck.

```
function toObject<T extends readonly string[]>(...keys: T) {
  return keys.reduce((acc, k) => {
    acc[k] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {} as any);
}
```

With `all` we're left with zero value but it's still almost better than not stating `as any` in the reducer. At least we can index the dictionary at run time. Had we left it alone the type would have been an empty object. Instead what I need is some way to convert an array of strings to union of the strings. Once I have that I can simply type the initial state of the reducer to:

```
{} as Record<UnionOfStrings, true>;
```

That said, I can't figure out how to do this conversion.

Anyone know how?

- [Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3BMw)

Comment: ```const arr = ["foo", "bar"] as const;

type Union = typeof arr[number];```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use `.reduce` for this, since it's really not much simpler than just using a plain-old `for` loop. Here's an implementation that I wrote using a `for` loop, but it can probably be written using `.reduce` as well, if you wish.

```js
function toObject<T extends readonly string[]>(...keys: T): Record<T[number], true> {
    const obj: Record<string, true> = {};

    for (const key of keys) {
        obj[key] = true;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Note the return type: `Record<T[number], true>`. I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: ahhh; happy to go with whatever looping structure but that `Record<T[number], true>` is a gem.